# Cocoapods update GoogleAnalytics sdk returns an SSL certificate error

Tags: ios, cocoapods, google-analytics-sdk

Ive just upgraded to version 0.37.1 of CocoaPods and now Im getting an error when trying to update my GoogleAnalytics library

In my podfile I have

```
pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK'
```

And now when I execute

```
pod update
```

I get the following error

> [!] Error installing GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK [!] /opt/local/bin/curl
>   -f -L -o /var/folders/v_/g79mcljx083bf8rp289mdy7r0000gq/T/d20150527-85393-io5rvl/file.zip
>   https://dl.google.com/googleanalyticsservices/GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS_3.12.zip
>   --create-dirs
>
> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
>   Current
>
> ```
>                              Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
> ```
>
> 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
>   --:--:--     0curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
>
> More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a
>   "bundle"
>
> of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
>
> bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
>
> using the --cacert option.
>
> If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
>
> the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
>
> problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
>
> not match the domain name in the URL).
>
> If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
>
> the -k (or --insecure) option.

Ive tried changing my podfile to use this pod but same error

```
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
```

Anyone know whats causing this? Is is related to the v0.37.1 update or an issue with the pods source?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might have something wrong with your curl itself and its ssl.

I had the same problem installing Google-Maps-iOS-SDK with cocoapods and the solution was to remove and install curl again.

If you're using brew, then it's just:

```
brew uninstall curl
brew install curl
brew link curl --force
```

Answer (score 1):

Cocoapods v0.37.2 is now available, try that!

Else you might try this :

- install rvm if needed (https://rvm.io/rvm/install)

So, in a console :

- rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
- pod setup --force
- pod install --verbose

This works for me, but i don't know which step was the workaround.

Comment: Just updated to v0.37.2 but same issue. 'rvm osx-ssl-certs update all' says all certs are up to date. 'pod setup --force' isn't valid, is there a typo here?  'pod install --verbose' is still giving the same error

Comment: mmm, try removing Podfile.lock and Pods directory, then "pod install" again. Else, maybe deintegrating (https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate) and installing again. If doesn't work, i don't know tell you anymore. I hope this be useful for you!